# Dense, codense, finite subcategory

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I found in some lecture notes a statement, that there exists an inclusion of full subcategory $\mathcal C \hookrightarrow \mathcal D$ which is both dense and codense, and moreover $\mathcal C$ is finite and $\mathcal D$ is large, however no example were given, so I'd appreciate to see such one

Comment: A trivial example would be an equivalence of categories, where $D$ is the result of adjoining to $C$ a class of isomorphisms.

Comment: Right, that's really a trivial example. Are there some similarly easy examples where we assume $\mathcal C$ to be essentially large?